# NodeJS API folder setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, directory

Pretty new to making API's and NodeJS apps. I have made a server.js file which has 2 routes

```
 app.get("/api/allinfo", function (req, res) {
      code...
 }
 app.get("/api/geo", function (req, res) {
      more code..
 }
```

current folder structure is

```
|-- node_modules
|-- server.js
|--package.json
```

The server.js file has everything in it

```
//Initiallising node modules
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var sql = require("mssql");
var app = express();

// Setting Base directory
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Setting up server
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
   var port = server.address().port;
   console.log("App now running on port", port);
 });

//Initiallising connection string
   var dbConfig = {
   user: "XXX",
   password: "XXX",
   server: "XXX",
   database: "XXX"
  };

      //API'S
//Get all the information we have about an address
app.get("/api/allinfo", function (req, res) {
    var query ='Select * from TABLE';
    executeQuery(res, query);
});

 //Function to connect to database and execute query
 var executeQuery = function (res, query) {
   sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
      if (err)
        console.log("Error while connecting database :- " + err);
      else{
        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();
        // query to the database
        request.query(query, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err);
                res.send(err);
            }
            else {
                    res.send(result)
            }
        });
    }
});
}
```

How do I rearrange this into a proper folder structure? 
What adjustments do I need to make to the code for this to happen?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_restful_api.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is the structure I use:

```
foldername
    controllers
    models
    routes
    utils
    db
    server.js
    package.json
    lib
    config
    middleware
    scripts
```

Comment: Great. @guruwinder a little more detail how server.js interacts with  those folders

Comment: All the files inside the routes folder are required inside server.js by a function that I have written. Now each of
these route files load their specific controllers which in turn require their models.
Config is injected by a config module. The DB folder contains all DB adapters written to abstract out the different database connections that we require.
Lib and utils contain common utility functions or custom libraries that I have created. These are loaded as and when required.